# Rust - Why do I need to pass a reference to a string as opposed to the string into std::io::read_line?

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm going through this Rust tutorial - https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html - and came across this block of code:

```
let mut guess = String::new();

io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

My confusion is why we need to pass a reference to the `guess` variable, as opposed to just the variable itself. Is there a reason it was designed this way?

In my understanding, `guess` is a pointer which holds a memory address. Then, if `guess` is dereferenced like so `*guess`, this will return the value at the memory address where the String is held.

So, it seems like the `read_line` function would only need the address of the String to read to. Ie, called like: `read_line(guess)` (or `read_line(mut guess)`).

I'm confused why this isn't possible, and why `read_line` is defined to take the reference to a String, which is the address of a 'pointer' (?) as opposed to just the String (pointer) itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values of type `String` *own* the memory holding the characters — they do contain a pointer to heap memory, and *when they are dropped, they deallocate that memory*.

If you pass a `String` to a function, you're *moving* the `String` and thereby transferring ownership of that memory. Then, at the end of the function, the `String` and its memory will be discarded unless the function *returns* the `String` value back to the caller:

```rust
fn moving_read_line(self, string: String) -> std::io::Result<(String, usize)> { ... }
```

This is less convenient and less flexible (for the caller) than accepting a mutable reference, which does not transfer ownership, only “borrows” it.

Comment: So is the benefit of ownership (the concept that variables have one owner, thus we can automatically deallocate at the end of scope) 1) Less error prone with regard to free() since I no longer have to manage when I free an object (avoiding mistakes such as forgetting to free, or free'ing the same memory twice) and 2) At the same time, it is faster than garbage collection because garbage collection does not free variables as soon as they are out of scope? I'm trying to reason why we can't just use garbage collection instead if the goal is to avoid mistakes with regard to freeing memory.

Comment: Or that may not be the goal, feel free to correct me. Still learning Rust so trying to wrap my head around all this :)

Comment: @WhoopsBing Rust's goal in this area is, *in part,* to avoid needing garbage collection, not for being "faster" but for being more consistent in timing (no GC pauses), and to avoid the requirements GC imposes (strictly controlled patterns of heap memory structures (which make FFI harder), among other things).

Answer (score 3):

The variable `guess` is actually not a pointer, but a struct that contains a pointer to some memory, as well as the size of that allocated memory.  If you dereference a String, you will get a slice, which has a pointer to the underlying memory, as well as the size of the window into that memory, but that pointer and size cannot be modified.  The slice is not the owner of the memory being referenced.  In order to modify the size or allocate new underlying memory for String, you need a reference to the String, hence the need for the mut reference